# Style.css is not applying after moving web files to ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, web-applications, apache2, config

I was building web application with CSS both external and internal working fine with XAMP local host

but when I moved files to the server (ubuntu with apache2) the pages are opening but some of the styles are not applying

Did anyone faced such a problem?

**EDIT**
I have found many solutions in the internet which involving setting up Reverse Proxy with mod_proxy so we can end our:
ProxyPass: / http://127.0.0.1/ with the dash "/" at the end and people say it resolve the issue but I am trying to figure another way without having to use the proxy any advice ?

Comment: have you seen error log?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Gurgolo , I checked apache error.log and found "session is enabled but no session modules have been configured, session not loaded: /style.css"

Comment: and if you try to reach the file directly from the browser what is the error code? 404?

Comment: @Gurgolo , No it shows css text